# operator += producing unexpected result javascript

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

```js
function range(start, end, st) {
  var arr = [];
  var counter = start;
  while (counter <= end) {
    arr.push(counter);
    counter += st || counter + 1;

  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(range(1, 10));
```

this produces unexpected result

however this:

```
counter = counter + st || counter + 1;
```

produces the expected result
any idea why?

Comment: might be helpful if you showed what it's giving you vs. what you expect

Comment: Because _operator precedence_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: @CrayonViolent it suppose to add 1 to counter if `st` wasn't provided since it will be undefined

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you expect the code to do, but `counter += st || counter + 1` is equivalent to

```
counter += (st || (counter + 1));
```

which is equivalent to

```
if(st) {
    counter = counter + st;
}
else {
    counter = counter + counter + 1;
}
```

On the other hand `counter = counter + st || counter + 1` is equivalent to

```
counter = (counter + st ) || (counter + 1);
```

which is equivalent to

```
if(counter + st) {
    counter = counter + st;
}
else {
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

So they do quite different things. I assume the operator precedence is throwing you off.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that

```
counter += st || counter + 1;
```

means the same as

```
counter = counter + (st || counter + 1);
```

whereas `counter = counter + st || counter + 1` means `counter = (counter + st) || (counter + 1)`.

---

In your example code `st` is `undefined`, so the loop effectively does

```
counter += counter + 1;
```

every time, which is equivalent to

```
counter = counter * 2 + 1;
```

Hence the large skips.

---

On the other hand, in

```
counter = counter + st || counter + 1;
```

`st` being `undefined` means `counter + st` is `NaN`, which counts as false, so this effectively runs

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

which is equivalent to

```
counter += 1;
```

However, this only works by accident. If you call your function with different arguments, such as:

```js
function range(start, end, st) {
  var arr = [];
  var counter = start;
  while (counter <= end) {
    arr.push(counter);
    counter = counter + st || counter + 1;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(range(-2, 2, 2));
```

The result is `[ -2, -1, 1 ]` instead of the expected `[ -2, 0, 2 ]`.

---

You can fix your code by doing

```
counter += st || 1;
```

instead.